# Dockerized Laravel Script Keeps Getting installation Screen On Google Cloud Run

Tags: laravel, docker, google-cloud-run

I have a laravel script that I have dockerized to run on GCP (cloud-run) . I also use GCsql.  The app needs to be installed when you first launch it. The installation works fine and the app seems to run for for about 10 minutes (seems random) then it suddenly displays the installation page again.  My suspicion is that the state that tells the app that it has already been installed somehow gets overwritten.

I am a newbie and need to figure out how to correct this. Below are my Dockerfile and Entrypoint files.  Can anyone offer some insight on this?

**Dockerfile**

````
USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY ./vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY . /var/www/html/

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage/*
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/.env

VOLUME ["/var/www/html/storage", "/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache"]

EXPOSE 80 443 3306 8080

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite```

**Entrypoint.sh**

```#!/bin/bash

source /etc/apache2/envvars
#tail -F /var/log/apache2/* &
exec apache2 -D FOREGROUND
#cd /var/www/html/
#php artisan migrate --force```
````

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run containers are not stateful. As your container scales up and down, due to inactivity or more load, it will lose its local filesystem. So any data you write to your local filesystem will be gone after a while, or when a second container instance comes up to serve the load. Please read the documentation carefully. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/developing